# Ordering a dictionary by value AND key in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
dic = {'s': 3, 'a': 2, 'w': 2, 'y': 2, 'x': 2, 'm': 4, 'd': 5}
```

And I need to order the elements first by VALUE, and in case the values are repeated, then sort by KEY, so I would get the following output:

```
dic = [('d', 5), ('m', 4), ('s', 3), ('a', 2), ('w', 2), ('x', 2), ('y', 2)]
```

I have tried using this code:

```
sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

But I keep getting the same output (the letters whose key is equal to 2 are not alphabetically ordered):

```
[('d', 5), ('m', 4), ('s', 3), ('a', 2), ('w', 2), ('y', 2), ('x', 2)]
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort the dict items with a key function that returns a 2-tuple with a negated value of the dict item as the first item, and the key as the second item:

```
sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0]))
```

This returns:

```
[('d', 5), ('m', 4), ('s', 3), ('a', 2), ('w', 2), ('x', 2), ('y', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, you need to include both the key and value in your lambda sort:

```
sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0]))
```

Comment: This answer gives a reverse alphabetical order, because `reverse=True`. `key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0]), reverse=False` would solve it, although this could cause other problems if the `-` operator is not defined for your objects.

Comment: Thank you, Nicolas. It worked fine. Can you explain me the logic behind the lambda function in this case? I can't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this definition of key

```
key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0])
```

Comment: This answer gives a reverse alphabetical order.